# BasicPopupMenuUI error

Tags: java, swing, popupmenu

I'm trying to make my own menu UI for Swing, but I'm coming across an error. I have my class that extends `BasicPopupMenuUI` and contains the following code:

```
public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
        return new ShadowMenuUI();
    }

    public Popup getPopup(JPopupMenu popup, int x, int y) {
        Popup pp = super.getPopup(popup, x, y);
        JPanel panel = (JPanel) popup.getParent();
        panel.setBorder(new ShadowBorder(3, 3));
        panel.setOpaque(false);
        return pp;
    }
```

If you were wondering, `ShadowBorder` is a class I have that extends `AbstractBorder` and paints the shadow as I would like it. When I start my application, the first thing I do is

```
 UIManager.put("PopupMenuUI", "ShadowMenuUI");
```

Then I continue on to create my GUI, and set the L&F (I'm using Nimbus for this application.) So does anyone see what I'm doing wrong, or if there is a better way to do what I'm doing?

EDIT: The error I'm getting is

```
UIDefaults.getUI() failed: no ComponentUI class for:
    javax.swing.JPopupMenu[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.
        basic.DefaultMenuLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border
        =com.apple.laf.AquaMenuBorder@165262ce,flags=8,maximumSize=,
        minimumSize=,preferredSize=,desiredLocationX=0,
        desiredLocationY=0,label=System,lightWeightPopupEnabled=true
        ,margin=,paintBorder=true]
java.lang.Error
```

Comment: What's the error you're coming across?

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot Oh, yes. Sorry, forgot to add that.
UIDefaults.getUI() failed: no ComponentUI class for: javax.swing.JPopupMenu[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.DefaultMenuLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=com.apple.laf.AquaMenuBorder@165262ce,flags=8,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,desiredLocationX=0,desiredLocationY=0,label=System,lightWeightPopupEnabled=true,margin=,paintBorder=true]
java.lang.Error

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem!!! Sorry to bother you with it, but my issue was when I put ShadowMenuUI, I forgot to inclue the package!